# Convert Text Books to Audiobooks?

Tags: pdf, convert, epub

I know that there are services, such as Zamzar that will convert a file type such as `ebpub` to an audio format such as an mp3. Is there such software on Ubuntu systems?

Comment: What is `ebpub`?  Do you mean `epub`?

Comment: text to audio via a synthetic voice is possible (I did it years ago using tools on GNU/Linux), but a *pdf* (*xml* file) is converted to text (removing formatting), fed into a voice synthesizer spitting out the ogg/mp3 file.  it was quick & easy; but the synth voice used wasn't the most pleasing to hear... these tools though are (or were) standard.  *i never tried epub & don't know if its format is easily converted*